# Как убрать из ссылки ?page=1 при возврате на первую страницу пагинации в Laravel 5.4?

Tags: php, laravel, pagination

В проекте на Laravel 5.4 есть множество подобных ссылок.

```
site.ru/?page=1
site.ru/category/item?page=1
site.ru/category/childCategory/item?mark=&model=?page=1
```

Как я понял, все они дублируют для SEO аналогичные без `?page=1`, что есть плохо.

Каким образом можно убрать из ссылок `?page=1` при возвращении на первую страницу пагинации во всем проекте?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Разобрался. Для решения вопроса нужно расширить стандартный пагинатор Laravel и в функции url() подменять '?page=1' на ''.
Выглядит это так:

```
<?php

namespace app\Http;

use Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator;

class SEOPaginator extends LengthAwarePaginator
{
    public function url($page)
    {
        if($page == 1){
            $url = str_replace('?page=1', '', parent::url($page));
            return $url;
        }
        else{
            return parent::url($page);
        }

    }
}
```

Теперь в любом контроллере, где это нужно меняем вызов стандартного пагинатора на расширенный.

Answer (score 1):

Простой костыль:

```
@if ($page==1)
   <a href="{{ str_replace('?page=1', '', $url) }}">{{ $page }}</a>
@else
   <a href="{{ $url }}">{{ $page }}</a>
@endif
```

Comment: А как это вставить во view? Ведь пагинация там генерируется {{$examples->render()}}

Comment: Такой костыль работать не будет